# Backbone URL Won't Update Using .navigate()

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

When parameters are passed into my Backbone App, I grab them and save them to local storage as options, and then the App starts auto-saving the user's progress as they work.  Now, I want to remove the parameters from the URL, so if the User refreshes the page, they won't have to start all over.

However, when I use the following code, the URL is not being updated.  I simply want to clear out all of the parameters.  And I don't want to run the Router function again so I've included `trigger: false`  Why doesn't Backbone allow me to do this?

```
  var newURL = "editor"
  App.Router.navigate(newURL, { replace: true, trigger: false });
```

**My Router**

```
routes: { 
  ""                    :              "browser",
  "editor"              :              "editor"
```

**Sample URL**

```
myapp.com/editor?param1=true&param2=false
```

**Note:**
Despite the `trigger: false` the router function is still being called.  The evidence is the fact that the page is loading twice.

Comment: Did you check your browser console for any possible errors?

Comment: Of course, no errors.

Comment: That behavior don't make sense, just in case, notice your code sample has `trigger: true` so make sense the route callback is called I cannot comment, sorry for the answer

Comment: Please give some more informations, like how and where you initialize your router and Backbone.history. With your given information I could not reproduce your problem. Maybe more of your router code could also help.